# What does this notation of defining a function mean?

Tags: general-topology

I have found this formulation there $f$ is a mapping, $f(x)(t) = t(x(t)+1)$

How am I supposed to correctly understand that? I mean is the left hand side the same as $f(x,t)$ or what is the idea of denoting it like that?

Update: More specifically, I must consider $C(0,1/2)$ with the sup-metric and let $f : C(0,1/5) \to C(0,1/2)$, where $f(x)(t) =$... Show that f is a contraction...

Comment: What is the tags related here? Also, what f map?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: I think it would really help to provide more context. What are the surrounding sentences of this formula?

Comment: $f$ is a function that takes a function $x$ and returns the function $t \mapsto t (x(t)+1)$.

Comment: f is described to be sub-metric and I have to show some contraction and find a unique fixed point etc. So I thought general topology and numerical analysis fitted? 

I found the notation in some notes of one of my professors.

Answer (score 2):

This notation is actually entirely straightforward.  What's going on is that $f$ is a function whose domain and range are both sets of functions.  So given a function $x$, $f(x)$ is another function.  To define the function $f(x)$, you need to say how to evaluate it on an input $t$.  That is, you need to define $f(x)(t)$.  The definition is that $f(x)(t)=t(x(t)+1)$.  Note that the $x(t)$ on the right-hand side is the function $x$ evaluated at $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is a function which takes $x$ to a function which maps $t \mapsto t(x(t)+1)$. This is sometimes called "currying".

Comment: Currying is more usually used to represent a two ($n$) parameter function as a one parameter function.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really feel sure. Would you please try to expand on this? :S